# how fix No module named parse in python3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

I am trying to run scripte python from github

but i have problem

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

ImportError: No module named parse
```

i need install this module for python3.4 on kali linux

Comment: You sure you are using python3? That looks very like you are using python2. You also don't install it, it comes with the standard library.

Comment: So what does `import urllib; print(urllib)` produce? There are two possibilities here: You have Python 2, not 3, or you have a local script named `urllib.py` somewhere that masks the standard library package. The `print()` call will reveal which of those two options is the case here.

Answer (score 5):

On python3 this will work

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
```

On python2 it's this

```
from urlparse import urlparse
```

Double-check your python version in `sys.version_info.major`.

Comment: Or, the OP has a `urllib.py` file masking the package.